# How to use Enum on phpunit tests with Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, enums, phpunit, laravel-9

I'm migrating a project from Lumen 8 to Laravel 9. I'm having problems using Enums; however, it worked in Lumen.

```
$router->patch('/orcamentos/{id}/situacao', [
    'uses' => AlterarSituacaoOrcamentoController::class . '@executar',
    'middleware' => ['pode:' . Permissao::VENDA_ORCAMENTOS_ALTERAR]
]);
```

**Enum**

```
namespace App\Models\helpers\Enums;

enum SituacaoOrcamento: string
{
    case Orcado = 'Orçado';
    case EnviadoAoCliente = 'Enviado ao cliente';
    case AprovadoPeloCliente = 'Aprovado pelo cliente';
    case RejeitadoPeloCliente = 'Rejeitado pelo cliente';
    case RejeitadoPelaEmpresa = 'Rejeitado pela empresa';
    case ConvertidoEmVenda = 'Convertido em venda';
}
```

**Test**

```
public function testaRetorno(): void
{
    $retorno = $this->patch('/orcamentos/1/situacao', [
        'situacao' => SituacaoOrcamento::AprovadoPeloCliente
    ]);

    $retorno->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

The error when running the test:

> Excepted a scalar, or an array as a 2nd argument to
> "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag::set()",
> "App\Models\helpers\Enums\SituacaoOrcamento" given.

The errors happen before even entering the controller. It occurs on the method set of class InputBag from Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation.

```
/**
 * Sets an input by name.
 *
 * @param string|int|float|bool|array|null $value
 */
public function set(string $key, mixed $value)
{
    if (null !== $value && !is_scalar($value) && !\is_array($value) && !$value instanceof \Stringable) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Excepted a scalar, or an array as a 2nd argument to "%s()", "%s" given.', __METHOD__, get_debug_type($value)));
    }

    $this->parameters[$key] = $value;
}
```

If I comment this `if` in the package file, it works. Maybe I'm doing something wrong that causes the issue.

Comment: I was able to overcome the error using `'situacao' => SituacaoOrcamento::AprovadoPeloCliente->value` in my test and at the beginning of the controller `$request->situacao = SituacaoOrcamento::from($request->situacao)`. But that is not a good solution in my opinion, it becomes to verbose. If Lumen could handle that on his own I believe there is a way to do it in Laravel too

Comment: Your issue is that you cannot pass an ENUM as part of the body because the enum is an object... and it cannot be "json encoded", need to pass a value (that the enum has)... This is purely a PHP error, has nothing to do with Laravel/Lumen...

Comment: @matiaslauriti It is not a PHP problem. Lumen would cast the value in the request from Enum to string and before the controller would cast it back from string to Enum. I expected Laravel to do the same. That is what I'm trying to do. Doing it manually with PHP I already did, but it's to verbose to use and I'm looking for this magic in Laravel. Maybe I'm missing some configuration.

Comment: Found a package that does what I wanted and more. [spatie/laravel-data](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-data)